# Der Artikel wird von ihm gelesen. (Passive voice object)

Tags: accusative, passive

Is Artikel the object in the following passive sentence?

Der Artikel wird von ihm gelesen. (The letter is read (is being read) by him).

What is being read? Der Artikel. So, it is the object but why is it preceded by Der?
Shouldn't it be preceded by *Den*? (accusative)

*Den* Artikel wird von ihm gelesen.

Answer (score 2):

No, *Artikel* is the **subject** in the passive voice sentence. It would be object only in the active voice counterpiece as:

> Ich lese den Artikel.

So *der* is the correct nominative case.

---

Update:

See a recipe for transforming an active voice sentence to a passive one here: [Lingolia, commercial site](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/verben/passiv)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what is the reason behind it? A person is reading an article. It doesn't make sense if the subject changes. I don't get it.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian: The very point of passive voice is that the thing which is operated on by the action is the subject.